# PHP loading items from the database into a div on load more button click

Tags: php

I have a main.php page where I have a while loop that displays the first 10 items from the database. I want to load the next 10 items once a load more button is clicked.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10");

if($res && mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $id = $row['id'];
   ?>
   <div class="main_page">
        item id <?php echo $id; ?>
   </div>

   <button class="load_more">Load More</button>
```

....

What is a good way of doing this? Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE:

right now i have this script for the load more button:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".load_more").click(function (){
            $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore.php?id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id"),
                success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $(".main_page").append(html);
                        $('.load_more').html('Load More');
                    }else{
                        $('.load_more').replaceWith('No posts');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

after the form of the filters is submitted, the url looks somewhat like this:
index.php?search=&category=0&ad_order=1

how do I pass on the search (even if empty), ad_order, and category value to the loadmore.php?

Comment: Could you please re-check that "not-correctly-enclosed" quote of your query?

Comment: oh I just copied it wrong.. I have the " " correctly. I will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the answer posted by Octern, not sure what you want to achieve for your second question but try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//saving the GET variables
ad = <?php echo $_GET['ad_order']; ?> 
catg = <?php echo $_GET['category']; ?>
search = <?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>
//default value of record to start from
rec = 0;

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".load_more").click(function (){
            $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                //passing them here
                //URL updated to pass rec
                url: "loadmore.php?id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id")+"&search="+search+"&category="+catg+"&ad_order="+ad+"&rec="+rec,
                success: function(html){
                    //updating counter to start from record
                    rec += 10;
                    if(html){
                        $(".main_page").append(html);
                        $('.load_more').html('Load More');
                    }else{
                        $('.load_more').replaceWith('No posts');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your `loadmore.php` you need to relevant code to fetch the above `$_GET` values

Your query will be something like:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds WHERE date < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' AND search = '".$_GET['search']."' AND category = '".$_GET['category']."' AND ad_order = '".$_GET['ad_order']."' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT '".$_GET['rec']."',10");
```

So everytime you click on the load_more, the limit will change as `LIMIT 0,10` -> `LIMIT 10,10` -> `LIMIT 20,10` etc.

Comment: in the loadmore.php, would it be like this: $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `date` < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' AND `search` = '".$_GET['search']."' AND `category` = '".$_GET['category']."' AND `ad_order` = '".$_GET['ad_order']."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10");
?

Comment: @Gadgetster Again, following from Octern's answer, you need to keep a track of the records to start loading from. I'll update my answer.

Comment: when I click load more now, nothing happens.. I did exactly what you said above

Comment: @Gadgetster Could you check your console to see if any error messages?

Comment: I don't see any errors. As soon as I remove the $_GET variables from the query code, it works (but not with the filter settings like I want it to)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48841/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-gadgetster)

Comment: @Gadgetster So could you paste the code along the lines where you have `innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

`limit 0, 10` will display the first 10 items from your query. `limit 20,10` will display 10 items starting with the 20th item (counting from zero). You can pass the page number or the number of items retrieved up to now in a parameter when you call the page that does the query. This will involve either reloading the current page with a different start index in `limit`, or issuing an ajax query that lets you load more items without reloading the page.

Comment: I have a loadmore.php page that has the following query: $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `date` < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10");
 this works but if I want to filter out the results, how can I get the loadmore.php to be effected? I tried using GET but it doesn't seem to take the url variables

Comment: Then there's an error in the page. Sending the variable in the URL should work. Try examining $_GET.

Comment: @Gadgetster You are not passing any `$_GET` variable at your limit. One thing, are you planning to have page refresh when clicked on 'load more posts' or without page re-load? The second approach is better from user's point of view and this requires AJAX.

Comment: I tried. In the query that in the main.php (in the actual long code) I have a $category_id where it sorts out the posts by the category id it relates to, i tried echo $_GET['category_id'] at the loadmore.php but it tells me undefined category_id even though I can see it in the url. Is it something to do with passing the variable through jquery somehow?

Comment: @Gadgetster Can you paste the URL where you can see this variable? Also you still haven't answered my question, please edit your question and explain how your pages are linked and how it should be shown in more detail.

Comment: Updated the question on top! They are linked with a jquery code that adds the new divs into the page